# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/projectCon] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc]

Tags: mysql, tomcat, jdbc, docker, jndi

I got a webapp deployed on a tomcat 8.0.41. The webapp should connect to a mysql server 5.7.

**Worth Mentionig**

Both the tomcat- and the mysql-server are running as docker-container. This is why the the msyql-url is: "jdbc:mysql://db:3306/ProjectDB". The jdcb-jar is added to the tomcat via docker-compose. But I think it should not be the source of the error.

**ConnectionBuilder.java**

```
package Persistence;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class ConnectionBuilder {

    public Connection conn;

    public ConnectionBuilder()throws NamingException, SQLException {

        Context intitialContext = new InitialContext();
        Context environmentContext = new InitialContext();
        environmentContext = (Context) intitialContext.lookup("java:comp/env");

        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) environmentContext.lookup("jdbc/projectCon");
        this.conn = dataSource.getConnection();
    }
}
```

**server.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/> 


  <GlobalNamingResources>

        <Recource 
            name="jdbc/projectCon"
            global="jdbc/projectCon"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            auth="Container"
            factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
            maxActive="15"
            maxIdle="3"
            maxWait="-1"
            removeAbandonedTimeout="300"
            defaultAutoCommit="true"
            username="admin"
            password="password"
            driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://db:3306/ProjectDB"
        />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

**context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/Project">
    <ResourceLink
        description="DB Connection" 
        name="jdbc/projectCon"
        global="jdbc/projectCon"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    />
</Context>
```

**web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" 
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

<recource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/projectCon</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</recource-ref>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

**StackTrace:**

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/projectCon] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:509)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketWithOptionsProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2445)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**This also happens at deploying:**

26-Feb-2017 21:49:15.201 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized Initializing Mojarra 2.2.14 ( 20161114-2152 unable to get svn info) for context '/project'

Comment: So many XMLs to accomplish a simple task of wiring in a DB connection (surely along with other similarly straightforward stuff). The same task would take about 4 lines of pure java code which you can compile, debug, understand when and how it gets called and write an integration test against it. Good luck sticking to your current architectural decisions.

Comment: Well this implementation should work too. I want this to work and thats why I am annoyed that it does not. Its not about the best way of implementation ;)